# how to use Requirejs to load a module made of multiple JS files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm new to JS so please forgive my ignorance. I wrote a code `main.js` that loads and uses a third party module:

```
const foo = require('foo');
...
var x = foo.DoSomething(data);
```

I installed the module `foo` with `npm install.` I can run `main.js` from terminal and it works. Now I want to build a single JS file that I could use in a browser. The problem is that the module `foo` is not just a code named `foo.js,` but a folder `./node_modules/foo/dist/` with 3 JS files in it: `a.js, b.js, c.js.`

I found out about Requirejs and I followed their manual to build a sample bundle out of `main.js` and some other module `bar` but **only** when it consists of a single file `bar.js.` When I'm trying to do the same with `foo,` I'm getting the error

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/greg/blabla/node_modules/foo.js'
```

Indeed `foo` is not a file but a directory that contains the code files. How do I get around this issue and load a **module made of multiple JS scrips** by referring to the module name and not to the individual JS file name(s)?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

Comment: BTW I also tried Browserify. It creates a single bundle JS file without complaints and I can see that this file actually includes the codes from all 3 of the module's JS files, but the bundled JS code fails to work in a browser because it still contains a require() call in it...

Comment: Thanks Ozan but I'm not sure how I can use the module creation. The module foo that my code needs to load was not written by me. It's a third party module. It already has a package.json file but no index.js file. I don't think I should edit the module written by someone else in order to use it for building my bundle with it.